# How to calculate accuracy based on predictor and true values in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate the accuracy of participants' response (column R) based on the correct response (column C). Some data is given in binary form (01010 - e.g. participant was wrong, correct, wrong, correct, wrong) and in letter sequences (i.e. the correct position of letters in a letter string).

See an example of the data:

```
dput(example) 
structure(list(TRIAL = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), EQ_C = c("0101", "1010", 
"1010", "00111", "01011", "01101", "100011", "010101", "001101", 
"0110011", "1101001", "1100101", "11100001", "11001010", "11001010"
), EQ_R = c("0101", "0010", "1010", "00111", "01011", "01101", 
"10101", "11010", "001101", "0100011", "1101001", "0100101", 
"11110001", "11001010", "11001010"), MEM_C = c("ZLHK", "RZKX", 
"DGWL", "BCJSP", "WRKTJ", "CHBXS", "HNDCWX", "SWVNDT", "WLDGPB", 
"DSHRKBV", "HCXLZWB", "HDNBVZC", "BCRHKVDM", "RVTBWKFS", "NWHVZFLD"
), MEM_R = c("ZLHK", "RZKX", "DGWL", "BCJSP", "WRKLTJ", "CHBXS", 
"HNDCWX", "SWVDTN", "WLDGPB", "DSHRKBV", "HCXLZWB", "HDNBVZC", 
"BCRHKVDM", "RVTBWKFS", "NWHVZFLD"), EQ_SUM = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MEM_SUM = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names             
 = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I added a new column for the "sum"/accuracy scores that need to be calculated for the binary data (EQ) and letters (MEM).

```
    OSPAN["EQ_SUM"] <- NA
    OSPAN["MEM_SUM"]<- NA
```

I then tried to calculate the sum based on another stackoverflow thread (using predictor and actual values), but somehow it does not recognise my variables. I suspect that I have the wrong data format as it keeps telling me that the obects cannot be found.

```
example$EQ_SUM <- round(100*rowMeans(EQ_C == EQ_R))

Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'EQ_C' not found
```

My question is: how do I match/calculate the accuracy or congruence between predictor (C) and actual (R) values into the sum columns? For instance, in row #1, EQ_SUM would be 1 (or 100%), whereas it would be 0.75 or 75% in #2, as the participant chose the wrong answer (0 instead of 1). Thus, partial credit scores are given, and it is not a matter of absolute match/congruence.

Thank you in advance. 
(I hope I did not leave out any vital information - it is my first time posting).

Comment: Hi, rather than an image, please provide a usable sample of your data using `dput`. Thanks

Comment: Seconding the request to include sample of your data using something like `dput(head(YOUR_DATA, 20))` so that we can get a sample of your data in the same format that you have.  Also wondering what you want to do in cases like row 7 where the `EQ_C` has different number of digits/letters than `EQ_R`.

Comment: For ways to measure differences between strings, check this out and see if you have any problems implementing: https://github.com/markvanderloo/stringdist

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you for the link, I will try it out! I edited the original post and added a sample of my data.
That is also something I asked myself - wondering what to do in cases where participants did not give an answer, thus having fewer responses in EQ_R compared to the correct ones in EQ_C.

Comment: @Jet I provided an excerpt from my data, I hope it works/is shown correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to calculate the accuracy of prediction vs. actual values - or as in your case participants response vs. actual response - is usually to do something like this:

`mean(EC_C == EC_R, na.rm = TRUE)`

Where EC_C and EC_R are the columns containing the values for which you want to calculate accuracy. You will receive a value between 0 and 1, the latter meaning 100% accuracy. Note that in this case, each pair of cells can either be identical or not. The above calculated accuracy would tell you how much percent of all cell pairs are identical. This would not be a suitable way if you want to compare single digits within each pair of cells - but for now it is not really clear to me what you are trying to do.

**Update**

Below you find an approach which will work, but only on rows where `EC_C` and `EC_R` have the same number of characters. In cases where repsondents leave an answer out, and there is no reccord which digit in the number/character string is missing, it is literally not possible to calculate the accuarcy, since it is not clear any more which digit/character corresponds to which question number. So the underlying assumption of my approach is that in a four digit string for example `EC_C = 1010` and `EC_R = 1000` the first digit in `EC_C` maps to the first digit in `EC_R`. In the case of `EC_C = 1010` and `EC_R = 101` it is not clear which digit in `EC_R` maps to which digit in `EC_C`. It could be the first three digits from the left, the accuracy would be 0.75 or it could be the first three digits from the right, in which case accuracy would equal to 0.

Beside this caveat my approach should work fine for all rows with euqal number of characters (given that the mapping is consistent). For all rows where the number of characters/digits is not the same my function will generate `NA`. If you want to use this approach to evaluate the result of student exams, then you would need to look into each exam where NAs have been generated and find out where a question was left out. It would save you a lot of trouble in the future, if you insert a special character at placed where answers have been left out.

```
library(stringr)
example <-
  structure(list(TRIAL = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                           "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"),
                 EQ_C = c("0101", "1010",
                          "1010", "00111", "01011", "01101", "100011", "010101", "001101",
                          "0110011", "1101001", "1100101", "11100001", "11001010", "11001010"),
                 EQ_R = c("0101", "0010", "1010", "00111", "01011", "01101",
                          "10101", "11010", "001101", "0100011", "1101001", "0100101",
                          "11110001", "11001010", "11001010"),
                 MEM_C = c("ZLHK", "RZKX", "DGWL", "BCJSP", "WRKTJ", "CHBXS", "HNDCWX", "SWVNDT",
                           "WLDGPB",  "DSHRKBV", "HCXLZWB", "HDNBVZC", "BCRHKVDM", "RVTBWKFS", "NWHVZFLD"),
                 MEM_R = c("ZLHK", "RZKX", "DGWL", "BCJSP", "WRKLTJ", "CHBXS",
                           "HNDCWX", "SWVDTN", "WLDGPB", "DSHRKBV", "HCXLZWB", "HDNBVZC",
                           "BCRHKVDM", "RVTBWKFS", "NWHVZFLD"),
                 EQ_SUM = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 MEM_SUM = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
            row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

# Function to calculate accuracy
check_accuracy <- function(x,y) {

    # Calculate a matrix which checks if the position of a character in x is corresponding to position in y
    check_mtr = str_split_fixed(x, "", max(nchar(x))) == str_split_fixed(y, "", max(nchar(y)))

    # Calculate the sum of all matching positions
    accuracy_sum = rowSums(check_mtr)

    # Subtract the number of empty strings from accuarcy_sum
    accuracy_sum2 = accuracy_sum - (max(nchar(x)) - nchar(x))

    # Divide sum of all non-empty matching positions by number of non-empty characters
    accuracy_vec = accuracy_sum2 / nchar(x)

    if (any(nchar(x) != nchar(y))) {
    warning("Number of characters in x and y is not corresponding. NAs generated.")
    ifelse(nchar(x) != nchar(y), NA, accuracy_vec)
    } else {
    accuracy_vec
  }

}

example$EQ_SUM <- check_accuracy(example$EQ_C, example$EQ_R)
example$MEM_SUM <- check_accuracy(example$MEM_C, example$MEM_R)
example
```

**Update 2:**
Please note, that the accuracy calculated in this approach is different than the approach using some measure of string distance. This will be clear, when looking at the result of row 8 in `MEM_SUM` which is `0.5`, since the respondent got only half of the answers right: compare `SWVNDT` to  `SWVDTN`, where the first three answers `SWV` correspond, the latter three don't. Measures of string distance, however, still consider the last three characters as related (`DTN` and `NDT`), since the letters are the same, just the ordering is different. The string distance measure here shows 0.67 which does not correspond to the accuracy of 0.5. Further, the string distance approach will also evaluate responses with answers left out (cases where the number of characters are not the same). However, without indication which answer is left out, a clear calculation is not possible, which is why my approach assigns here an `NA` together with a warning message.

The result should look like this

```
   TRIAL     EQ_C     EQ_R    MEM_C    MEM_R    EQ_SUM MEM_SUM
1      1     0101     0101     ZLHK     ZLHK 1.0000000     1.0
2      2     1010     0010     RZKX     RZKX 0.7500000     1.0
3      3     1010     1010     DGWL     DGWL 1.0000000     1.0
4      4    00111    00111    BCJSP    BCJSP 1.0000000     1.0
5      5    01011    01011    WRKTJ   WRKLTJ 1.0000000      NA
6      6    01101    01101    CHBXS    CHBXS 1.0000000     1.0
7      7   100011    10101   HNDCWX   HNDCWX        NA     1.0
8      8   010101    11010   SWVNDT   SWVDTN        NA     0.5
9      9   001101   001101   WLDGPB   WLDGPB 1.0000000     1.0
10    10  0110011  0100011  DSHRKBV  DSHRKBV 0.8571429     1.0
11    11  1101001  1101001  HCXLZWB  HCXLZWB 1.0000000     1.0
12    12  1100101  0100101  HDNBVZC  HDNBVZC 0.8571429     1.0
13    13 11100001 11110001 BCRHKVDM BCRHKVDM 0.8750000     1.0
14    14 11001010 11001010 RVTBWKFS RVTBWKFS 1.0000000     1.0
15    15 11001010 11001010 NWHVZFLD NWHVZFLD 1.0000000     1.0
```

Comment: thank you, I edited the original post and added sample data and some clarification as to what I am trying to calculate. I have tried calculating the Levenshtein distance as it is weighted, but again, this does not give me a relative accuracy score (i.e. comparing single digits and not absolute congruence). Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated the answer according to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the `stringdist` package.

```
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)
example %>%
  mutate(EQ_RIGHT  = nchar(EQ_C) - stringdist(EQ_R, EQ_C, method = "lv"),
         EQ_SUM    = EQ_RIGHT / nchar(EQ_C),
         MEM_RIGHT = nchar(MEM_C) - stringdist(MEM_R, MEM_C, method = "lv"),
         MEM_SUM   = MEM_RIGHT / nchar(MEM_C))
```

The 'lv' method seems like a pretty good fit here, but there are other options. *Levenshtein distance: Minimal number of insertions, deletions and replacements needed for transforming string a into string b.*

```
   TRIAL     EQ_C     EQ_R    MEM_C    MEM_R    EQ_SUM   MEM_SUM EQ_RIGHT MEM_RIGHT
1      1     0101     0101     ZLHK     ZLHK 1.0000000 1.0000000        4         4
2      2     1010     0010     RZKX     RZKX 0.7500000 1.0000000        3         4
3      3     1010     1010     DGWL     DGWL 1.0000000 1.0000000        4         4
4      4    00111    00111    BCJSP    BCJSP 1.0000000 1.0000000        5         5
5      5    01011    01011    WRKTJ   WRKLTJ 1.0000000 0.8000000        5         4
6      6    01101    01101    CHBXS    CHBXS 1.0000000 1.0000000        5         5
7      7   100011    10101   HNDCWX   HNDCWX 0.6666667 1.0000000        4         6
8      8   010101    11010   SWVNDT   SWVDTN 0.6666667 0.6666667        4         4
9      9   001101   001101   WLDGPB   WLDGPB 1.0000000 1.0000000        6         6
10    10  0110011  0100011  DSHRKBV  DSHRKBV 0.8571429 1.0000000        6         7
11    11  1101001  1101001  HCXLZWB  HCXLZWB 1.0000000 1.0000000        7         7
12    12  1100101  0100101  HDNBVZC  HDNBVZC 0.8571429 1.0000000        6         7
13    13 11100001 11110001 BCRHKVDM BCRHKVDM 0.8750000 1.0000000        7         8
14    14 11001010 11001010 RVTBWKFS RVTBWKFS 1.0000000 1.0000000        8         8
15    15 11001010 11001010 NWHVZFLD NWHVZFLD 1.0000000 1.0000000        8         8
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach. Nevertheless, although the results of a string distance approach look similar to the check_accuracy function I provided, the underlying concept is different and yields different results.